# Can't customize color of default search component

Tags: sass, ionic3, scss-mixins

I have an Ionic 3 app I'm working on where I have a search field. I'm trying to color it with a dark background and white text.

I have the following code, which works fine on the background, but the default icon and placeholder text are not turning white:

```
  .searchbar {
    background-color:#2f303e; 
    color:#fff;
      .searchbar-input {
        background-color:#2f303e; 
        color:#fff;
      }
  }
```

Here is the component:

```
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/
in Sass variable section
there you have $searchbar-ios-input-search-icon-color and many more variables you need to declare them in theme/variables.scss
simply add them and it will do.

Happy coding..:)

Answer (score 0):

The default search icon used is a svg (used as background image). It's color cannot be changed by using `color: #fff;`

Instead use the sass variables available for **icon color**:

`ios: $searchbar-ios-input-search-icon-svg`

`android: $searchbar-md-input-search-icon-color`

For **placeholder color**:

`ios: $searchbar-md-input-placeholder-color`

`android: $searchbar-ios-input-placeholder-color`